# How can I install Native Instrument Machine drivers in a Windows 7 VM?

Tags: linux, virtualization

I just recentlty installed Arch Linux on my home computer. I have a lot of audio software and equipment that I wanted to use, so was trying to set it all up so I could still use it. However,I was unable to install my Native Instruments Maschine controller with Wine. If this was possible, I would do this. (So if you know how to get it to run in Wine, please share! The installer keeps telling me to insert the original DVD)

Since I was not, I created a Windows 7 VM in Virtualbox. However, when I plug in the Maschine controller, I get a driver error. I manually install the provided drivers, but the driver error persists. It says the device cannot start and gives error code 10.

Is there something that I forgot to configure in Arch, as far as USB goes? Any ideas?

Note: I am talking about the Maschine physical controller, not the Maschine software. The software works just fine, it's the device that is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Maschine physical controller is connected by USB you probably need to configure the VM in VirtualBox to allow it access to the physical host USB ports through virtual USB ports in the emulated virtual machine.

See http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#idp17344784

Comment: Is that different from using the Devices pulldown menu? I have given it with the pulldown menu and Windows sees the Maschine, just cannot start the driver. I will try this when I get home though.

Comment: Turns out I hadn't checked use EHCI :)